# Create dictionary from splitted strings from list of strings

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, split

I feel that this is very simple and I'm close to solution, but I got stacked, and can't find suggestion in the Internet.
I have list that looks like:

```
my_list = ['name1@1111', 'name2@2222', 'name3@3333']
```

In general, each element of the list has the form: `namex@some_number`.
I want to make dictionary in pretty way, that has `key = namex` and `value = some_number`. I can do it by:

```
md = {}
for item in arguments:
    md[item.split('@')[0]] = item.split('@')[1]
```

But I would like to do it in one line, with list comprehension or something. I tried do following, and I think I'm not far from what I want.

```
md2 = dict( (k,v) for k,v in item.split('@') for item in arguments )
```

However, I'm getting error: `ValueError: too many values to unpack`. No idea how to get out of this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You actually don't need the extra step of creating the tuple

```
>>> my_list = ['name1@1111', 'name2@2222', 'name3@3333']
>>> dict(i.split('@') for i in my_list)
{'name3': '3333', 'name1': '1111', 'name2': '2222'}
```

Comment: This is so good, thank you!. Looks like I've tried to do it too in complicated way.